# How to decrease multiple spans about -10px for each span that has different top px

Tags: sass

Is there a way on scss to decerase multiple spans by 10px if they have different sizes for example:
One span has top:23px, another has 25px I need to be able to decrease for 10px

I tried using calc(-10px) but no luck

```
<span style="top:23px;">aosidjiasj</span>
<span style="top:29px;">aosidjiasj</span>
<span style="top:19px;">aosidjiasj</span>
<span style="top:20px;">aosidjiasj</span>
```

I except to decrease by 10px

```
<span style="top:13px;">aosidjiasj</span>
<span style="top:19px;">aosidjiasj</span>
<span style="top:9px;">aosidjiasj</span>
<span style="top:10px;">aosidjiasj</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use `transform: translateY(-10px);` (if the display type is not inline)

```
span {
    display: inline-block;
    transform: translateY(-10px);
}
```